# When using jacoco for code coverage of a tomcat web app, how to get coverage from WEB-INF/lib classes?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm getting coverage of everything in src/main/java, but the vast majority of my code actual is in the webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder. Other modules are compiled into jar files and put into there to form the web app. I have full access to the source of each of those jar files. How can I get jacoco to watch them and generate coverage for them?

Comment: Simply get the coverage while those dependencies are built. That's the way it's done.

Comment: I don't even know what you mean :(

But, I'm actually calling APIs against this server while it's running via external tests, and I'm trying to see what code paths are triggered by those tests. So any data I might get during a build is not so useful.